# SQLIte compare datetime

Tags: ios, sqlite, datetime

What is the easiest way in ios app to compare datetime string in sqlite3.
I store the datetime string in following way.

```
NSDateFormatter* df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSString* dtString=[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

then I'm inserting dtString into the table. So after i want to retrieve all rows for example only for last two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite3 doesn't contain a `DATETIME` type so you need to think of ways of encoding it.

If you want to use the date column in a `WHERE` clause then you could store the `time_t` returned from `gmtime(time(NULL))` (i.e. the time now, since UNIX epoch) and then use some simple clause to get those rows:

```
... WHERE date >= ?
```

And binding that `?` to `gmtime(time(NULL)) - 60**60*24*2`

EDIT: If you want to stay completely in Objective-C, then the same date value can be determined from an `NSDate` object using:

```
(time_t)[date timeIntervalSince1970]
```

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

but there are datetime functions, which i think might help, what about using strftime(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)?

Comment: My approach was to make it trivial for the database to do the filtering, hence encoding it as a simple integer.

Comment: and how to convert NSDate to that integer?

Comment: `(time_t)[date timeIntervalSince1970]`.

Comment: oops , i forgot about this method :)